# Delete row from X-editable with confirmation (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I added a confirmation to the **delete** button, I noticed that the row has not been removed, and the code work fine.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" confirmed-click="removeUser($index)" ng-confirm-click="Would you like to delete this user?">del</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.directive('ngConfirmClick', [
    function(){
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var msg = attr.ngConfirmClick || "Are you sure?";
                var clickAction = attr.confirmedClick;
                element.bind('click',function (event) {
                    if ( window.confirm(msg) ) {
                        scope.$eval(clickAction)
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

This is the [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/643/).

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to replace:

```
scope.$eval(clickAction)
```

by

```
scope.$apply(clickAction)
```

Working [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/645/).